# Is it possible to connect Jenkins Groovy Pipelines with Artifactory?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a **Groovy Pipeline** with **Jenkins 2.32.1**
I can read Pipeline definition from

- Pipeline script
- Pipeline script from SCM (Git, Mercurial or Subversion)

[image]

Is there any method or plugin to read from artifactory,
something like "Pipeline script from Artifactory"?

Comment: Why is it in Artifactory? It should be within Source Control.

Comment: You can save the scripts as text files and deploy them to Artifactory, HOWEVER, and as @Oscar wrote, why? Artifactory is a binary repository manager and as such it's purpose is to store binaries. It should not replace the vcs such as github/bitbucket ect...

Comment: Could you reply to the comment?